# Unable to print result in spfx react (got the data)

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react-webpart

Getting data from SPFX React (json) -

```
this.state = {
      testProperty1: "",
      hideDialog: true,
      showModal: false,
      items: [
        {
          Id: "",
          title: "",
          updated: "",
          FileLeafRef: ""
        } as IItem
      ] as IItem[]
    } as IReactDocumentLibraryState;

 pnp.sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle("Student%20Details%20No%20Content%20Type")
      .items.select(
        "Id",
        "Title",
        "FileLeafRef",
        "Student_x0020_Class",
        "Created"
      )
      .top(50)
      .orderBy("Modified", true)
      .get()
      .then((_items: any[]) => {
        console.log(_items);

        this.setState({ items: _items, testProperty1: "test data 2" });
      });
```

**Got the data from console.log from browser -**

```
    (2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
Created: "2019-01-29T08:46:07Z"
FileLeafRef: "pnp.JPG"
ID: 4
Id: 4
Student_x0020_Class: "Class #1"
Title: "Title 1"
odata.editLink: "Web/Lists(guid'fa2e74fc-2c1c-4980-ae46-88cc856df7c1')/Items(4)"
odata.etag: ""3""
odata.id: "6b7072b4-b0b6-4933-800e-cf850a503bad"
odata.type: "SP.Data.Student_x0020_Details_x0020_No_x0020_Content_x0020_TypeItem"
__proto__: Object
1: {odata.type: "SP.Data.Student_x0020_Details_x0020_No_x0020_Content_x0020_TypeItem", odata.id: "1022114e-ab80-4cb3-a07c-39d433ea18c3", odata.etag: ""3"", odata.editLink: "Web/Lists(guid'fa2e74fc-2c1c-4980-ae46-88cc856df7c1')/Items(3)", Id: 3, …}
length: 2
```

**Render in SPFX react - **

```
{this.state.items.map(myitems1 => {
          //if (myitems1.Id != "") {
          return (
            <div key={myitems1.Id}>
              <span>{myitems1.title}</span>
              <div />
            </div>
          );
          // }
        })}
```

**Error getting -**

message: "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"
stack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined↵    at eval (eval at  ()↵ )"

**I think the object is not gets parsed .**

```
_items[0]
{odata.type: "SP.Data.Student_x0020_Details_x0020_No_x0020_Content_x0020_TypeItem", odata.id: "0a8a5f9e-a1b3-4a0f-87ad-e9c2a7e1f9d8", odata.etag: ""3"", odata.editLink:
```

I am not getting data in render block ( How to check the state in render block ? ).

Please help .

Comment: Seems like you are not referencing `this` correctly.  If the error is "Cannot read property 'state' of 'undefined'" then at the point where you are trying to access `this.state`, `this` is undefined.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the Interface .. property . The property cumming from online not matching with interface ... typecasting error .

Thanks .

Comment: @BISWANATHHALDER Could you provide your working sample as answer?